# How to execute one liner command of sqlite3 query with nested strings from adb shell?

Tags: windows, sqlite, adb, su

I want to execute a one liner command of SQLite 3 with nested string from adb shell.

The follwing command WORKS:

```
adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db """SELECT * FROM sms WHERE read=1""";"
```

However this command DOESN'T WORK:

```
adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db """SELECT * FROM sms WHERE address="+0012345" """;"
```

As you note I have change 'read=1' in 'address="+0012345"'
The problem is that SQLite 3 select format of sms must be TEST/STRING and not a number.
Therefore, the select command ends in (address=") and doesn't absorb what's after it (+0012345"')

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

***update*** for another trial that failed for me, but maybe will give someone direction:

I tried to add ".explain" in the command line so I see what command the sqlite3 gets.

```
adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db .explain \"SELECT * FROM sms WHERE address=\`\"\`\"+0012345\`\"\`\"\";\""
```

output is

```
/system/bin/sh: ": not found
/system/bin/sh: ": not found
sqlite3: Error: too many options: "SELECT * FROM sms WHERE address="+0012345""
Use -help for a list of options.
/system/bin/sh: ": not found
```

so it seems that the sqlite3 is getting the phone number with quotes "+0012345" as requested!
However, when I remove the ".explain" like this

```
adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db \"SELECT * FROM sms WHERE address=\`\"\`\"+0012345\`\"\`\"\";\""
```

I get this output:

```
/system/bin/sh: ": not found
/system/bin/sh: ": not found
/system/bin/sh: ": not found
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: dos command line, running on windows

Comment: The [dos] tag is only for questions regarding the long obsolete 16-bit MS-DOS operating system and its clones.  Do not use it for questions about the Windows command line.

Comment: Does the windows shell support heredocs?

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself with:

```
adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db \"SELECT * FROM sms WHERE address=\"\\\"+0012345\"\\\"\"\"\";"
```

go figure:)